# How to handle named entity (&ast;) in xml while make xslt to browse file?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

xml file:

<para>here is entity "**&ast;**" </para>

Desire Output:

<p>here is entity "*****" </p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare the entity:

```
<!DOCTYPE para [
<!ENTITY ast "*">
]>
<para>here is entity "&ast;" </para>
```

The XSLT code simply transforms `para` to `p` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```